# Which of the following cache designer guidelines are generally valid?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

Which of the following cache designer guidelines are generally valid?

1. The shorter the memory latency, the smaller the cache block
2. The shorter the memory latency, the larger the cache block
3. The higher the memory bandwidth, the smaller the cache block
4. The higher the memory bandwidth, the larger the cache block

As per my understanding, 4 stands valid since larger memory bandwidth leads to a large cache block size. However what is the relation between cache block and latency?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What makes you think there is *any* relation between the two?  What characteristics are you holding fixed, and what are you allowing to vary?

Comment: I do not think there is a relation between latency and size of cache block. The cache block has a relation with bandwidth since a higher bandwidth would allow more bits at any time, hence I said I think 4 stands @D.W.

Answer (score 1):

None of the guidelines are *generally* valid in the sense of providing strong guidance in the absence of other considerations.

Presumably the intent of the exercise was to recognize that increasing block size is a crude form of prefetching which tends to reduce the number of misses at the cost of wasting memory bandwidth (and cache capacity) when the extra memory data is unused.

When memory bandwidth is abundant, the cost of wasting bandwidth is lower making larger cache blocks less expensive. When cache miss latency is lower the cost of a cache miss is lower, reducing the benefit of prefetching; this reduces the benefit of larger cache blocks.

Lower memory latency also reduces the benefit of a larger cache when performance is limited by latency as is often the case (assuming performance is the primary goal). A smaller cache will tend to favor smaller cache blocks since the prefetching from larger blocks wastes capacity and also increases cache conflict (a larger cache block links the cache way for sub-blocks, so cache replacement is less flexible potentially increasing misses even if all sub-blocks are accessed before eviction, i.e., when the prefetching is accurate).

Since increasing the size of memory requests facilitates increasing memory bandwidth, larger cache blocks can be more attractive for the sake of increasing bandwidth.

Larger cache blocks (memory access chunks) reduce per block metadata overhead. Standard SECDED ECC only adds one bit for each doubling of size (at modest reduced protection) and the per-block size of some metadata (such as directory storage for large-scale cache coherence) is independent of block size.

Larger blocks also reduce tag overhead; for a given capacity doubling the block size halves the number of tags. Tag overhead can be more significant if the tag storage is implemented in a less dense but faster technology than the data storage (e.g., SRAM vs. DRAM) or if tag storage is on the processor chip while data storage is off-chip (adding chips to increase capacity is less expensive than adding area to a chip). (A similar effect is *theoretically* possible if reducing tag overhead reduces chip area just enough to fit on a maximum-sized chip or even to meet a chips per wafer goal, but the benefit of increasing last-level cache capacity by less than 10% is small.)

Since the miss reducing benefits of larger block size can be provided by very slightly more intelligent prefetching, the benefit of larger block size is typically more constrained to increasing memory bandwidth (e.g., GPUs typically have a larger memory fetch block size) and/or reducing tag overhead (from number of tags or metadata per stored byte). A simple adjacent block prefetcher can provide the same effect as doubling block size with the advantage of being able to be turned off when such prefetching seems not worthwile. A next block prefetch would avoid fetching a likely less useful adjacent but lower-addressed chunk (the next in address order chunk is often more likely to be accessed than the previous chunk).